# CakePHP 3.6: fetchAll()with conditions

Tags: php, sql, search, cakephp, filter

I would like to add search functionality in my view. The problem is that I get data from raw sql like this so I dont know how to filter the results:

```
        $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $stmt = $conn->execute('SELECT c.id as customerid, CONCAT(c.name, " ", c.surname) as customer, s.title as title, s.length, cs.created , DATE_ADD(cs.created, INTERVAL s.length DAY) as expiring_date, DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(cs.created, INTERVAL s.length DAY), NOW()) as days_left
                                FROM customers c 
                                JOIN customer_service_types cs on c.id = cs.customer_id
                                JOIN service_types s on cs.service_type_id = s.id
                                WHERE s.is_subscription = 1 and DATE_ADD(cs.created, INTERVAL s.length DAY) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
                                ORDER BY expiring_date');
        $expiringServices = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
        //debug($expiringServices,true);

        $this->set(compact('expiringServices'));
```

Is it possible to `filter` the results by a form input? I want the user to filter the results by entering the name in a text field and compare it with `customer` field which returns from the `sql query`. One guess is the `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, fun_name)` but I dont know how to implement it.

Comment: Simply use the query builder instead of raw queries which are usually prone to SQL injections and use this plugin https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search - Read its documentation.

Comment: @burzum thank you for your suggestion but I am quite novice in CakePHP and for me its too complicated query to use the query builder

Comment: Yea, life is complicated, never learn anything new, that's of course a proper solution... ;) Wrong profession if you don't want to learn new things. Just read the manual https://book.cakephp.org

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is to fetch the user entered data and then pass it to the `where` condition using `like` query condition then the result you will get will be sorted according to the user entered data (or form data)

Comment: @Exterminator but this will raise SQL injection vulnerability, isn't it?

Comment: no, you can use `mysql` functions `mysql_real_eacape_string` to prevent that

Comment: Just use the ORM and query builder... It will take care of the sensitization automatically.

Comment: @Exterminator it seems that I can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` in cakephp

Comment: you can use this then `Sanitize::escape($string, $connection)`